# Multiselect combobox in ASCX

Tags: asp.net

I am designing an user control in ASCX similar to which is shown in the link below http://easylistbox.com/demoMultiDropDown.aspx
I am using textbox with Div around and image for arrow and a listbox group control for multiselect option and wrote a javascripts to show and hide the listbox when onclick of image arrow

I could achieve everything except when I click on outside the list is not disappearing 
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'onmouseout' event of div and set the display style to none for the div. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Please Don't forget to mark as answer, if it fix your problem :-)

Comment: suppose i click on the arrow and my checkbox list appears and when i go to check some items then the onmouseout event triggers and the checkbox list gets disappears rite... :(

Comment: No, i guess. Thats why i told you to trigger the mouseout event on the Div with checkboxes, but not on the associated textbox. Ok? Give a try and let me know. If that works,please don't forget to mark as answer. :-))